# Tweak VBA to delete all Columns that fit criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that moves through row 2 and deletes a `Column` if a cell is `blank`.

The delete parts work, but I have to run it N times to remove all the columns if there are N blank cells adjacent to one another, is it possible to delete all columns in one pass as I do not know how many blank cells might be next to one another.

Thanks

```
Sub delete-columns()
For Each cell In Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(2, ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.count))
    If cell.Value = "" Then cell.EntireColumn.Delete xlToRight
Next cell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will delete all columns in the active sheet with blanks in row 2:

```
Sub DeleteColsWithBlanks()
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet

Set ws = ActiveSheet
With ws
    .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(2, .Columns.Count)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireColumn.Delete
End With
End Sub
```